# How to sort by specific order in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm working with some api data and I want to sort it by a specific order `const entryOrder = ['first', 'second', 'third']`

the data I'm trying to access from the api is `program.number`

I'm trying to accomplish this in react by creating a function and calling it later but not having any luck. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is what I have tried:

```
  const entryOrder = ['first', 'second', 'third']
  const orderEntry = (number) => {
    number.sort(function (a, b) {
      return entryOrder.indexOf(a) - entryOrder.indexOf(b)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please add to the question : Your attempt, input data and desired output.

Comment: Can you provide details on what you've tried. It would be easy to understand your requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by the following:

```
const orderEntry = (p1, p2) => {
    const entryOrder = ['first', 'second', 'third']
    return entryOrder .indexOf(p1.program.number) > statusOrder.indexOf(p2.program.number) ? 1 : -1
  }
```

then calling the `orderEntry` on my api sort like so  `fullPrograms.sort(orderEntry)`